# ASP.NET : Get PixelColor on mouse click on asp.net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, getpixel

I have an asp.net page which displays different colors..It looks something like this.

[image]

Now what i want is,when i click on any where in that form,i want to get the pixel color of that particular point. How can i do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use jquery and put a click event on each of the area's. I'd put the colour into the id of each of the areas, something like id="colour-#d9d9d9".

Comment: though i didn't got the perfect answer i was searching for..this answer made me think in a different perspective and i got my problem solved